# JavaFX VBox not aligning inside a GridPane

Tags: javafx, gridpane, vbox

I'm trying to build a calculator in JavaFX and a VBox is not aligning with the other nodes inside the GridPane.

I'm using a GridPane as my root node, and placing individual buttons at each cell location.

The right most column is a VBox which contains a column of buttons.

The problem is this VBox is a few pixels off from the other buttons - it won't align. This is what I see: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGLvG.png)

I've tried setting the alignment of the VBox but this makes no difference. What am I missing?

```
package calculator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.*;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class UserInterface extends Application {

    private static int appWidth = 200 * 3;
    private static int appHeight = 310 * 3;
    private static int numRows = 7;
    private static int numCols = 8;
    List<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_MODENA);

//Create 0-9 buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Button tempButton = new Button(Integer.toString(i));
            tempButton.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            HBox.setHgrow(tempButton, Priority.ALWAYS);
            buttonList.add(tempButton);
        }

//Point button
        Button point = new Button(".");
        point.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

//Multiply and division buttons
        Button multiply = new Button("X");
        multiply.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        VBox.setVgrow(multiply, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Button divide = new Button("/");
        divide.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        VBox.setVgrow(divide, Priority.ALWAYS);

//Plus and minus buttons
        Button plus = new Button("+");
        plus.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        VBox.setVgrow(plus, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Button minus = new Button("-");
        minus.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        VBox.setVgrow(minus, Priority.ALWAYS);

//Equals button
        Button equals = new Button("=");
        equals.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        VBox.setVgrow(equals, Priority.ALWAYS);

//Clear and delete buttons
        Button clear = new Button("AC");
        clear.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

        Button del = new Button("Del");
        del.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

//Screen label
        Label screen = new Label("0");
        screen.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        screen.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

//Create GridPane
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

//Create VBox to contain right column buttons
        VBox rightCol = new VBox(divide, multiply, minus, plus, equals);
        VBox.setVgrow(rightCol, Priority.ALWAYS);
        rightCol.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

//Add nodes to grid pane
        grid.add(buttonList.get(0), 0, 6, 4, 1);
        grid.add(point, 4, 6, 2, 1);
        //grid.add(equals, 6, 6, 2, 1);

        grid.add(buttonList.get(1), 0, 5, 2, 1);
        grid.add(buttonList.get(2), 2, 5, 2, 1);
        grid.add(buttonList.get(3), 4, 5, 2, 1);
        //grid.add(plus, 6, 5, 2, 1);

        grid.add(buttonList.get(4), 0, 4, 2, 1);
        grid.add(buttonList.get(5), 2, 4, 2, 1);
        grid.add(buttonList.get(6), 4, 4, 2, 1);
        //grid.add(minus, 6, 4, 2, 1);

        grid.add(buttonList.get(7), 0, 3, 2, 1);
        grid.add(buttonList.get(8), 2, 3, 2, 1);
        grid.add(buttonList.get(9), 4, 3, 2, 1);
        //grid.add(multiply, 6, 3, 2, 1);

        grid.add(clear, 0, 2, 3, 1);
        grid.add(del, 3, 2, 3, 1);
        //grid.add(divide, 6, 2, 2, 1);

//Add the right column        
        grid.add(rightCol, 6, 2, 2, 5);

        //Add the screen
        grid.add(screen, 0, 0, 8, 2);

        //Set row and column constraints
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < UserInterface.numRows; rowIndex++) {
            RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
            rc.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            rc.setFillHeight(true);
            rc.setPercentHeight(UserInterface.appHeight / UserInterface.numRows);
            grid.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        }
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < UserInterface.numCols; colIndex++) {
            ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
            cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            cc.setFillWidth(true);
            cc.setPercentWidth(UserInterface.appWidth / UserInterface.numCols);
            grid.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        }

        grid.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

// Create the scene and the stage
        //grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, appWidth, appHeight);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want those buttons aligned, why don't you put them into the `GridPane`? Different parents may determine the positions of the children in a different way. You can't be sure a `VBox` layouts children idendical children the same way as a `GridPane` with a single column let alone one with additional children in different columns.

Comment: Thanks that’s helpful to know. I’m just experimenting with it at the moment. I can put them directly the GridPane, I was planning to apply some specific css to these buttons and thought it would be helpful to have them contained the in their own box. What is the best practice in this situation?

Comment: Ok, I think I have worked out the answer to this - create additional style class names and assign these to the buttons in question. Thanks for clarifying my initial question.